# How to handle button overlaps in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, uibutton, core-graphics, swift4

I am trying to implement standalone clickable buttons that are semicircles shown in the image below. My problem is that the button frames overlap each other which causes the other buttons to not be clickable. Is there a way to make the button frame the same shape as the one being rendered or are there any other possible workarounds?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add all the buttons to one SKSpriteNode, then when clicked get the click position in this main SKSpriteNode and manually calculate which segment has been clicked.